# Android ListView performance - weird allocations

Tags: android, performance, listview, expandablelistview

I've implemented an ExapndableListView (and the question is pretty generic about ListView).

I've added this simplified code example (without the other views coz the problem is the same without them).

The problem is that when I scroll, there are some allocations I cannot understand. **For the first 10-20 new cells (approximately) that's being presented when I scroll there is allocation of 3-4 MB +- and for the rest cells it takes 1 MB for about every 20 cells.**

As far as I know it shouldn't allocate anything after the list is loaded, just reuse the appropriate cells.

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    EventListItem object = (EventListItem) sections.get(groupPosition)
                                                .getItemAtIndex(childPosition);

    ViewHolder holder;
    if ( hView == null ) {
        hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.popularity_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();
    }
    holder.id = object.getId();

    holder.title.setText(object.getTitle());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    String      id;
}
```

What might be the problem? 
What might it allocate when I scroll?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

For one, take out the line `View hView = convertView;` and just use `convertView` in the function. The link you create there is useless.

Other than that you shouldn't be worrying about the allocations here. ListView does a ton of optimizations for you and may be using/releasing objects quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks but what optimization can take such amounts of memory? and is it reasonable for a list to take 6-8 MB?

Comment: Depends on the model you are using for the list. `EventListItem object = (EventListItem) sections.get(groupPosition).getItemAtIndex(childPosition);` may be causing your memory to go up. The code you posted is implementing that function properly, but maybe the issue is somewhere else?

Comment: Why are you worrying about the memory the OS allocates for your ListView? Are you seeing performance problems with your list?

Comment: Because I know that after it's loaded it should reuse the allocated cells and in GGDB I see those few MBs when I scroll and thats very weird. I have a tabbed view with 3 lists and each takes like 6 MB so it's accumulated to lots of wasted memory.